# Remover espacio entre un input y un button en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

¿Cómo puedo remover el espacio que existe entre el `input` y el `button`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="list_messages"></ul>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Si comento estas columnas simplemente mi input se pone por encima del button -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message">
        </div> <!-- -->
        <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Si comento estas columnas simplemente mi input se pone por encima del button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Send message</button>
       </div> <!-- -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ponlos en el mismo div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando se llama [**Button addons**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) de Bootstrap.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul id="list_messages"></ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

En cambio si quieres ahorrarte marcado puedes utilizar flexbox y crear tu propio componente.

```
  <div class="flex-input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Send message</button>
  </div>
```

```css
.flex-input-group {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-input-group input,
.flex-input-group button {
  flex: 1;
  /* Distribuye el espacio entre los dos elementos. */
}
.flex-input-group input {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  flex-grow: 5;
  /* Reduce este número para hacer el input más pequeño. Actualmente crece 5 veces si hay espacio en el contenedor */
}
.flex-input-group button {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul id="list_messages"></ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="flex-input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Inclusive puedes cambiar el orden de los elementos con la propiedad `order`.

```css
.flex-input-group {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-input-group--inverted {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-input-group input,
.flex-input-group button {
  flex: 1;
  /* Distribuye el espacio entre los dos elementos. */
}
.flex-input-group input {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  flex-grow: 5;
  /* Reduce este número para hacer el input más pequeño. Actualmente crece 5 veces si hay espacio en el contenedor */
}
.flex-input-group button {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.flex-input-group--inverted input,
.flex-input-group button {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.flex-input-group--inverted input {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.flex-input-group--inverted button {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul id="list_messages"></ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="flex-input-group flex-input-group--inverted">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sin cambiar el html tendrías que sobreescribir el estilo de bootstrap para eliminar el "gutter" de cada columna:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .panel-body > .row > .col-md-6:first-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  .panel-body > .row > .col-md-6:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="list_messages"></ul>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Si comento estas columnas simplemente mi input se pone por encima del button -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message">
        </div> <!-- -->
        <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Si comento estas columnas simplemente mi input se pone por encima del button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Send message</button>
       </div> <!-- -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo no me funciona y al ejecutarlo muestra el `input` encima del `button`

Comment: Si te fijas, es para resoluciones superiores a 992px, tal y como funciona bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haría yo, solo con tal de no poner más `css` es:

1. Mover la clase `.row` hacia los `div` internos
2. Poner la clase `.col-xs-12`, `.col-sm-12`, `.col-md-12` o `.col-lg-12` *(según el que estés usando, en este caso para que sea visible en este `snippet` uso `.col-xs-12`)* en el lugar de la clase `.row` para respetar el `padding` de los laterales

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="list_messages"></ul>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message">
        </div> <!-- -->
        <div class="row col-xs-6">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Send message</button>
       </div> <!-- -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aunque tu solución funciona, no sigue las buenas prácticas de anidación de bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" width="100%" type="button">Send message</button>
     </span>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
   </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
```